# Can I obtain a Class Object for a local variable of a method using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

If I have a variable defined in a method,can I get its Class Object using reflection

```
public void check(List<?> String> list){

   Map<String,String> map // do something

}
```

Can i Obtain the Class Object to perform reflection for list and map variables,both are local variables

Comment: Do you mean `map.getClass()`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No.. I mean to getMethod("check") and then access the method variables class type

Comment: Do yo mean `Method m = map.getClass().getMethod("check")`, and then `m.invoke(map, null)`?

Comment: @AVolpe no actually.I just want to access the local variable in a method and perform reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, reflection does not expose local variables. Byte code analysis may help, but I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Then why can we access generic parameter types of a method using Method.getGenericParameterTypes() ??? Arent parameters local to a method as java is pass by value?

Comment: @KumarAbhinav I don't know how you are relating pass-by-value with generic parameter declarations. Method parameter types are part of method declarations. Reflection does expose type and method declaration information. It does not expose implementation details of methods.

Comment: I now understood what you are trying to say..we can access the declaration information (generic declaration type ) but not use the value of those parameters themselves to perform reflection on them